# Meaning of a passage from Dickens' "Little Dorrit" Ch.25

Tags: meaning, comprehension

> A professor of writing occupied the first-floor, and enlivened the garden railings with glass-cases containing choice examples of what his pupils had been before six lessons and while the whole of his young family shook the table, and what they had become after six lessons when the young family was under restraint.

1. What are the "glass cases"?
2. What is "choice examples of his pupils before and after six lessons"?
3. What does "family shaking the table" mean?

The whole passage is difficult to comprehend. Can someone please simplify the given passage so that it is easier to understand?

Comment: He's a handwriting teacher. He's displaying 'before and after' examples of his students' writing - the 'before' examples deliberately made worse by having his children shake the table while the student was writing on it, to show how much his teaching has improved their handwriting.

Comment: This isn't proofreading - the passage wasn't written by the OP.

Comment: @KateBunting Just as proofreading is a hole that has no bottom, so too are "Rewrite this big chunk of text for me using only the 200 words of English I already know" requests not constructive. They will never help anybody else, and they are incredibly open-ended and endless. We haven't the foggiest idea what the petitioner does not know and why they do not know it, nor how to address this.

Comment: @tchrist - '"Rewrite this big chunk of text for me using only the 200 words of English I already know" - at last! Someone else feels the way I do!

Comment: @KateBunting - if it _was_ written by the OP, it's bloody good.

Comment: @KateBunting Well spotted on the table-shaking front, I must admit that I was struggling with that part of the extract.

Comment: While this isn't proofreading, it's cut from the same cloth because it's a "bottomless" request, as @tchrist has pointed out. Questions on this site must be about specific aspects of learning English. "I don't understand this whole paragraph" doesn't qualify. THAT SAID, this passage is bloody difficult to understand, which makes it feel less like it's on that slippery slope, and I'm willing to look the other way

Comment: @gotube - 'this passage is bloody difficult to understand' - do you really think so?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I do. I couldn't parse it my first couple times through, then after reading Kate's gloss it made sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is no longer being dismissed as 'proofreading', I'm converting my comment to an answer.

He's a handwriting teacher. He's displaying 'before and after' examples of his students' writing in glass cases. The 'before' examples have been deliberately made worse by having his children shake the table while the student was writing on it, to show how much his teaching has improved their handwriting.